# Mobx: change states in action without runInAction still works

Tags: reactjs, mobx

In mobx [documentation](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html):

> action only affects the currently running function, not functions that are scheduled (but not invoked) by the current function! This means that if you have a setTimeout, promise.then or async construction, and in that callback some more state is changed, those callbacks should be wrapped in action as well!

This above mean, I should wrap state changed with `runInAction`, like this following:

```
class App {
    @observable logined = false
    @action async login(payload){
        runInAction(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.logined = false 
            }, 1000)
        })
    }
}
```

Above works, but the weird is if i remove the `runInAction` block, code still works, this behaviour is inconsistent with the document said.

please check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wytwyt02/2qkv8a76/3/).

Comment: In addition to @mweststrate answer I can say you are using `runInAction` wrong. You should not use *async* code such as `setTimeout` inside `runInAction` handler. Correct way is `setTimeout(() => runInAction(() => this.logined = false), 1000)`

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is correct; unobserved data can be modified at will, as it cannot lead to further side effects, see: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310

Also not that it is always allowed to change state outside of actions as long as strict mode is not enabled (`mobx.useStrict(true)`)

A PR to reflect this new behavior better in the docs would be appreciated! https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/gh-pages/docs/refguide/action.md

Comment: In the above code, using `action` in the exact place where we used `runInAction` will also work. So what's the use of `runInAction`? I have gone through the docs (https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/7c9e7c86e0c6ead141bb0539d33143d0e1f576dd/docs/refguide/action.md) and it has similar examples, so the advantage of using `runInaction` is not clear to me.

Comment: `runInAction(fn)`, is the same as `action(fn)()`. So the first one is useful for one-time (or 'anonymous') actions.

Comment: Does `action(fn)()` here mean invocation of `action`? I have tested that in scenarios like above, `action(fn)` in place of `runInAction(fn)` also works fine, so whats the need for the extra `()` after `action(fn)`?

Comment: Then you made a mistake in testing, it is like `fn.bind(x)` versus `fn.bind(x)()`, some difference, action just creates a new function, but without further invocation doesn't actually run it.

Answer (score 0):

An "action" allows you to make multiple state changes in one "batch" -- if you are only making one change, you don't need it.